# Substitute pig trotter for powdered gelatine in an aspic

Tags: substitutions, stock

I'm intending to make a raised game pie, which involves making aspic from the stock.

The recipe says to make 1 pint of stock from the game bones and trimmings, herbs, root vegetables, and to **whisk in a 0.4oz sachet of powdered gelatine** before chilling the stock.

However I'm aware that the traditional method of producing savoury jelly for pies is to use pig's trotters.

How many pig's trotters should I use to produce 1 pint of aspic for a pie? Is there anything I should know that I might not have thought of?

Comment: I like to add closure to these questions. In the event I made 600ml of stock from 1kg of pig bones and three pig's tails. The butcher had no trotters available, and assured me that tails are as good a source of gelatine. The resulting jelly is suitably solid at room temperature, and I got some good nibbling out of the meat in the tails.

Comment: glad to hear it worked out. the tails definitely contain a ton of gelatin and you could have done well with the ears and head as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the biggest problem is your not going to be able to judge how much gelatin any given pigs foot is going to produce, hence the recipe calling for extracted gelatin to sort of foolproof the recipe. But if your going to try and make it with just the pig's feet I would suggest having a look at this recipe here for "Trotter gear"

http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2011/03/recipe-for-a-healthy-jar-of-trotter-gear.html

Anything coming from Fergus Henderson is going to be awesome. It recommends 6 feet and that recipe produces a pot's worth of stock so I think that will suffice for you.